# ASP.NET MVC: контроллер

Tags: c#, asp.net

Начинаю разбираться в ASP.NET MVC, до этого писал на PHP на MVC фрейворке kohana, по этому голова как бы варит, но тут не могу вкурить на самом начале, вот стандартный контроллер и мой метод User

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult User()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

создал view с названием User.aspx, по идее должен его вызвать так: http://localhost:8080/WebSite1/Home/User/, а консоль говорит 404. Расскажите эти основы пожалуйста, что и куда.

Другие методы работают, все норм.

И вот ещё что, пишу например так

```
public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return "Hello, world!";
            }
```

а стандартная страница проекта не меняется, в чем подвох?

Comment: 1. Въюха User.aspx находится в папке Home?
2. попробуйте return Content("Hello World!");

Comment: Да. В папке home. Консоль сервера IIS Express.
Тоже ничего не меняется. Грузится стандартная страница ASP.NET MVC